# Windbg wrong symbols msvcr80

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps, debug-symbols

I'm investigating a w3wp crash on our production machines, I'm loading the crashdump with windbg with the following settings:

- SRV*C:\MicrosoftSymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;C:\MySymbols
- sym noisy

(also tried symbol path http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028)

Why can't it still not load the msvcr80 symbols?

> 0:025> !analyze -v
>
> ---
>
> - *
> - Exception Analysis                                   *
> - *
>
>   ---
>
> DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\w3wp.exe\45D6968E5000\w3wp.exe - OK DBGENG:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\w3wp.exe\45D6968E5000\w3wp.exe - Mapped
>   image memory DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\mscorwks.dll\4889DC18590000\mscorwks.dll -
>   OK DBGENG:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\mscorwks.dll\4889DC18590000\mscorwks.dll -
>   Mapped image memory SYMSRV:  mscorwks.pdb from
>   http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 4599999 bytes - copied
>   DBGHELP: mscorwks - public symbols
>           c:\microsoftsymbols\mscorwks.pdb\37AFE5AF09D54705B6B685CBCD2208FC2\mscorwks.pdb
>   DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\mscorlib.ni.dll\4889DC80af7000\mscorlib.ni.dll
>   - mismatched DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\mscorlib.ni.dll\4889DC80af7000\mscorlib.ni.dll
>   - mismatched DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\mscorlib.ni.dll - file not found DBGHELP:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\mscorlib.ni.dll -
>   file not found SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\mscorlib.ni.dll\4889DC80af7000\mscorlib.ni.dll
>   - file not found DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\mscorlib.ni.dll - file not found DBGHELP:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\mscorlib.ni.dll -
>   file not found SYMSRV: 
>   c:\microsoftsymbols\mscorlib.ni.dll\4889DC80af7000\mscorlib.ni.dll not
>   found SYMSRV: 
>   http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/mscorlib.ni.dll/4889DC80af7000/mscorlib.ni.dll
>   not found DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\mscorlib.ni.dll - file not found DBGHELP:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\mscorlib.ni.dll -
>   file not found DBGHELP: mscorlib.ni.dll not found in c:\mysymbols
>   DBGHELP: mscorlib.ni.dll not found in c:\mysymbols DBGENG: 
>   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\9adb89fa22fd5b4ce433b5aca7fb1b07\mscorlib.ni.dll - Couldn't map image from disk. Unable to load image C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\9adb89fa22fd5b4ce433b5aca7fb1b07\mscorlib.ni.dll,
>   Win32 error 0n2 DBGENG:  mscorlib.ni.dll - Partial symbol image load
>   missing image info DBGHELP: Module is not fully loaded into memory.
>   DBGHELP: Searching for symbols using debugger-provided data. SYMSRV: 
>   mscorlib.pdb from http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 117111
>   bytes - copied
>   *** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for mscorlib.ni.dll DBGHELP: mscorlib_ni - public symbols
>           c:\microsoftsymbols\mscorlib.pdb\E47AF49130474776AF6C5994C50088421\mscorlib.pdb
>   DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\kernel32.dll\49C51F0A102000\kernel32.dll -
>   OK DBGENG:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\kernel32.dll\49C51F0A102000\kernel32.dll -
>   Mapped image memory SYMSRV:  kernel32.pdb from
>   http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 416879 bytes - copied
>   DBGHELP: kernel32 - public symbols
>           c:\microsoftsymbols\kernel32.pdb\BE496DC9472F4438B080C70594D8F9CC2\kernel32.pdb
>   SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\user32.dll\45E7C67691000\user32.dll not
>   found SYMSRV:  user32.dll from
>   http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 266731 bytes - copied
>   DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\user32.dll\45E7C67691000\user32.dll already
>   cached DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\user32.dll\45E7C67691000\user32.dll already
>   cached DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\user32.dll\45E7C67691000\user32.dll - OK
>   DBGENG:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\user32.dll\45E7C67691000\user32.dll -
>   Mapped image memory SYMSRV:  user32.pdb from
>   http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 293451 bytes - copied
>   DBGHELP: user32 - public symbols
>           c:\microsoftsymbols\user32.pdb\B29B53A483EA4F5DAF2BF0FB1A4E7DB92\user32.pdb
>   DBGHELP: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\ole32.dll\45D70AA5139000\ole32.dll - OK
>   DBGENG:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\sym\ole32.dll\45D70AA5139000\ole32.dll - Mapped
>   image memory SYMSRV:  ole32.pdb from
>   http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 1014574 bytes - copied
>   DBGHELP: ole32 - public symbols
>           c:\microsoftsymbols\ole32.pdb\DC8A079CAE0B4A0C89EC5A936EAF1F7F2\ole32.pdb
>
> FAULTING_IP:  msvcr80!terminate+4d 781346b4 e820460000      call
>   msvcr80!_SEH_epilog4 (78138cd9)
>
> EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
>   ExceptionAddress: 781346b4 (msvcr80!terminate+0x0000004d)
>   ExceptionCode: 40000015   ExceptionFlags: 00000000 NumberParameters: 0
>
> DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS
>
> PROCESS_NAME:  w3wp.exe
>
> ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x40000015 - {Fatal Application Exit}  %hs
>
> EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x40000015 (1073741845) - {Fatal
>   Application Exit}  %hs
>
> APP:  w3wp.exe
>
> MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE No export dumpstack found
>
> PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  WRONG_SYMBOLS
>
> BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS
>
> LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00000000 to 781346b4
>
> STACK_TEXT:   14b98e30 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   msvcr80!terminate+0x4d
>
> FOLLOWUP_IP:  msvcr80!terminate+4d 781346b4 e820460000      call
>   msvcr80!_SEH_epilog4 (78138cd9)
>
> SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0
>
> SYMBOL_NAME:  msvcr80!terminate+4d
>
> FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
>
> MODULE_NAME: msvcr80
>
> IMAGE_NAME:  msvcr80.dll
>
> DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4889d619
>
> STACK_COMMAND:  ~25s; .ecxr ; kb
>
> FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_40000015_msvcr80.dll!terminate
>
> BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS_msvcr80!terminate+4d
>
> WATSON_STAGEONE_URL: 
>   http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/w3wp_exe/6_0_3790_3959/45d6968e/msvcr80_dll/8_0_50727_3053/4889d619/40000015/000046b4.htm?Retriage=1
>
> WATSON_IBUCKET:  977211931
>
> WATSON_IBUCKETTABLE:  1
>
> Followup: MachineOwner

Regards,

Michel

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Windbg need access to .dll file itself to be able to locate the .pdb
(if the actual dump don’t contain enough of the header)

Find the msvcr80.dll from the crashed machine, and locate it by
File->Image File Path, and .reload